# Whats wrong with my delete method in LinkedList (generic)?

Tags: java, class, generics, linked-list

**I changed the LinkedList class, but it still does not work**

**LinearNode class**

```
 public class LinearNode<T>{


  private LinearNode<T> next;
   private T element;

   public LinearNode()
   {
      next = null;
      element = null;
   }

   public LinearNode (T elem)
   {
      next = null;
      element = elem;
   }

   public LinearNode<T> getNext()
   {
      return next;
   }
   public void setNext (LinearNode<T> node)
   {
      next = node;
   }

   public T getElement()
   {
      return element;
   }

   public void setElement (T elem)
   {
      element = elem;
   }
}
```

**I can't figure out the problem with delete method in my java generic class**

public void delete(T element){

```
LinearNode<T> previous = list; 
LinearNode<T> current = list;
boolean found = false;

while (!found && current != null)
{
    if (current.getElement ().equals (element)) {
        found = true;
    }
    else {
        previous = current;
        current = current.getNext();
    }
}
//found loop
if (found)//we fount the element
{

    if(current == this.list){
           previous.setNext (null);
           this.last = previous;
       }

   else
       if(current == this.last){
           this.last.setNext(null);
           this.last.equals(previous.getElement()); 

       }
       else{

           previous.setNext(current.getNext());
           current.setNext (null);
       }

this.count--;
}
```

}

I have also my driver class which will delete the element from the linked list

also here the part of driver class

```
public void delete(){

        Teacher aTeacher;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String number;
        aTeacher = new Teacher();

        System.out.println("Now you can delete teachers from the programme by their number.");
        System.out.println("Please input number:");
        number = scan.nextLine();

        if (aTeacher.getNumber().equals(number)){
        teachers.delete(aTeacher);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("There are no any teacher with this number.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could start by explaining which problem you are experiencing. Also pleas provide the code for the class `LinearNode`

Comment: You say that you have a problem... Which is?

Comment: I can't delete an object from my driver class. I also added some code from my Driver class and LinearNode class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a few problems in your code.

This loop is a little odd

```
while (current != null && !current.getElement().equals(element))
{
    previous = current;
    current = current.getNext();
    found = true;
}
```

You shouldn't be setting `found = true` inside the loop on every iteration, because then you will always believe that you found the element after the loop is done. If you pass in values that you know exist in the list, then you wouldn't notice a problem. If you pass in values that are not in the list, then you will likely see `current` set to `null` later in your code.

I might write this instead

```
while (! found && current != null)
{
    if (current.getElement ().equals (element)) {
        found = true;
    }
    else {
        previous = current;
        current = current.getNext();
    }
}
```

This block is a little odd too

```
       if(current == this.last){
           this.last.setNext(null);
           this.last.equals(previous.getElement()); 
       }
```

Neither of these statements seem like they would have any effect. The value of `last.getNext ()` should already be `null`. `this.last.equals(previous.getElement())` is merely testing whether the last node is equal to the **element** held in the next to last node; that evaluation should always be `false` and hopefully has no side-effects.

I might write this instead

```
       if(current == this.last){
           previous.setNext (null);
           this.last = previous;
       }
```

Finally, though it's not a problem for the delete *per se*, I would still be thorough here and make sure that the node being removed doesn't retain any references into the list.

So this

```
       previous.setNext(current.getNext());
```

might become this

```
       previous.setNext(current.getNext());
       current.setNext (null);
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me and wrote a lot of comments. They will be very helpful for me.